# How to convert string in format yyyyMMdd to date using SSIS expression?

Tags: ssis

I have a date *`20130131`* in csv which I'm trying to convert to *`2013-13-01`* using Derived Column in SSIS. I have used this expression but it does not seem to work.

> (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(DATE_DECISION_TO_REFER,1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(DATE_DECISION_TO_REFER,3,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(DATE_DECISION_TO_REFER,5,2))

How do I rewrite this expression to produce the correct output with a value of data type `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Check this **SUBSTRING([DATE_DECISION_TO_REFER],1,4)   + "-" + SUBSTRING([DATE_DECISION_TO_REFER],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([DATE_DECISION_TO_REFER],7,2)**

Comment: Hey Zero, go ahead and post your answers in the answers area.

Comment: @KyleHale Siva has already posted the same with explanation too :)

Comment: I know, I meant in the future ... it was the right answer! : )

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per *Kyle Hale* suggestion, below is my answer

```
SUBSTRING([DATE_DECISION_TO_REFER],1,4) + "-" +
SUBSTRING([DATE_DECISION_TO_REFER],5,2) + "-" + 
SUBSTRING([DATE_DECISION_TO_REFER],7,2)
```

To educate you so that you will never face this issue again, this is how expression works

```
 Get 4 characters from DATE_DECISION_TO_REFER starting at position 1, add a dash,
 get 2 characters from DATE_DECISION_TO_REFER starting at position 5, add a dash, 
 get 2 characters from DATE_DECISION_TO_REFER starting at position 7.
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank You everyone!!! Kyle thanks for your answer and especially for educating me much appreciated.

Comment: thank you for this - another forum had SUBSTRING using a 0 based index which would not parse.. I should have checked SO first.

Answer (score 27):

[Fast Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139833.aspx) is a much more elegant solution

1. Add a **Data Conversion** Data Flow Component.
2. Right click, Show Advanced Editor...
3. Goto Input and Output Properties
4. Expand Data Conversion Output and click on the date column
5. Set **FastParse** to True in the Custom Properties
6. Make sure the data type is set to **database date [DT_DBDATE]**
7. Run the ssis package again the yyyymmdd dates should flow smoothly from **nvarchar** to **date**

Comment: there's a step between 1 and 2.  Open normally and add the column with the text that needs to be converted and name the output column. Then Close and continue to step 2.

Answer (score 11):

#### Expression:

You should use the expression to format the date to *`yyyy-MM-dd`* like shown below. This expression will format the incoming value `20130131` to `2013-01-31` and then will convert to appropriate data type. The expression uses the incoming column named `Column0`.

> (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(Column0,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Column0,5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Column0,7,2))

#### Issue:

Your expression is taking the value *`20130131`* and then incorrectly converting it to the value *`20-13-01`*. This is an invalid format for dates and hence the expression is failing to type cast it to `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` data type.