# Importing yyyyMMdd Dates From CSV in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, derived-column

I have 12 columns using the *yyyymmdd* format. In the *Data Flow Task*, I have a *Flat File Source*, a *Derived Column Task* and an *OLE DB Destination*. I'm applying the following expression to these fields in the *Derived Column Task*:

```
(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING((DT_STR,10,1252)([Date_Column]),1,4) + "-"
+ SUBSTRING((DT_STR,10,1252)([Date_Column]),5,2) + "-"
+ SUBSTRING((DT_STR,10,1252)([Date_Column]),7,2))
```

It keeps making me convert the field before I substring it, but I have the fields set up as *DT_STR* in the *Connection Manager*. The destination field is in *DATE* format in SQL Server. SSIS always shows the "could not be converted because of a potential loss of data" error. I've checked the raw data in the CSV and don't see any dates that look out of place. Everything fits the format.

I've also attempted to use a *Data Conversion* task as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296769/how-to-convert-string-in-format-yyyymmdd-to-date-using-ssis-expression), but ended up getting the same kind of error. Any recommendations? The answers I've seen on here all point to the use of a *Derived Column* task, but several others I've mentioned this to have had the same problem I'm having.

EDIT: Here's a sample of the data. The field specifically mentioned in all of the errors is CRTFCTN_DT. There are 470 fields in the dataset, but this does show the first two date fields.

[image: Sample]

**SOLUTION:** In the *Connection Manager*, I changed the *yyyymmdd* fields to DT_STR(10) (8 characters for the date, 2 for the added dashes), and rebuilt my *Data Flow Task*. This solved the problem. If you DON'T rebuild the task, the *Derived Column* task won't pick up on the new data type. Once the task was recreated, I also no longer needed to cast the dates as strings before applying substring.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is interpreting the field as integer.  That might explain the loss of data warning as well as the need to Cast the field before using string operations on it.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your csv, just a few rows?

Comment: The casting error specifically mentions that Substring doesn't work with DT_DBDATE.

Comment: @grichmer try casting to `DT_DATE` .. take a look at my answer and give a feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You setup column [Date_Column] as DT_STR in  Connection Manager. What is the length you specified? by default it is 50. In Derived Column, you used its  length as 10, which is the error message "could not be converted because of a potential loss of data".

Comment: You called it. I had set up the date fields with a length of 8. I changed this to 10 and rebuilt the Data Flow Task. Now it works! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try casting as `(DT_DATE)` instead of `DT_DBDATE`

```
(DT_DATE)((SUBSTRING((DT_STR,50,1252)([Date_Column]),1,4) + "-"
+ SUBSTRING((DT_STR,50,1252)([Date_Column]),5,2) + "-"
+ SUBSTRING((DT_STR,50,1252)([Date_Column]),7,2)))
```

**You can do this workaround**

Assuming that the date column name is `inColumn`

In the DataflowTask, Add a script component , Mark `inColumn` as input column, add a new Output column `outColumn` with dataType DT_DBTIMESTAMP

*Change script language to vb.net*

[image]

*Mark your date column as Input*

[image]

*Create an Output column for each date column*

[image]

Inside the script, in `Input0_ProcessInputRow` sub use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) Function as follow:

*In this example the date column is `MailReceivingDate`*

```
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent


    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

        If Not Row.MailReceivingDate_IsNull AndAlso
              Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.MailReceivingDate.Trim) Then

            Row.outColumn = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.MailReceivingDate.Trim, "yyyyMMdd", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"))

        Else

            Row.outColumn_IsNull = True

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Double click on the script component. And go to script tab. Then click on design script button. It will open a vs editor

Comment: And it is dt_date not db_date

Comment: I've tried using DT_DATE instead, but I get the same error. As for the second portion of your comment, I'm attempting it, but Script Component is a new one for me. Do I need to put that line of code in there once for each date field?

Comment: If all has the same issue yes.

Comment: I'm getting several semantic errors saying that 1) I need to define the column names and 2) *DateTime*, *New* and *System.Globalization.CultureInfo* do not exist in the current context.

Comment: @grichmer if interested in date conversion in ssis read this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035354/ssis-source-format-implicit-conversion-for-datetime/42038060#42038060