# SSIS Get Date from a File Name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis

My file is called ...  File - 20170101.xlsx

I have the following as a variable

FilePath,  data type string, File - 20170101

as a derived column  I have

```
(DT_I8)LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],8),4)
```

I Got this to work, but only gives me part of the values..(only 3 numbers, I need 8)

gives me output of 101.. do I need to save the file name as a different date format? I have tried File - 01012017

I have tried this but it does not work

```
(DT_I4)LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],8),4)
```

I am trying to get the 20170101, then I was going to add a data conversion to turn it into a date

it does not work..any ideas please

Comment: It would be a lot easier to create a script component instead of trying to parse the string using VBScript functions

Comment: _What are the four numbersyou get?_ Based on your sample data you should just use `(DT_I8)RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],8)`. But perhaps your sample data is incorrect. It helps if you actually describe the output.

Comment: gives me output of 101.. do I need to save the file name as a different date format? I have tried File - 01012017

Comment: your formula will result in 101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the value of the variable `FilePath` is *not* `File - 20170101` as you stated, it is `File - 20170101.xlsx` right?

Please take care when writing your question.

You can solve these things yourself with just a bit of experimentation.

Firstly,

```
RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],8)
```

gives you

```
101.xlsx
```

Therefore,

```
RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13)
```

will give you

```
20170101.xlsx
```

and

```
LEFT(RIGHT(@[User::FilePath],13),8)
```

will give you

```
20170101
```

To turn that into a date is trickier.

This explains how to do it

[How to convert string in format yyyyMMdd to date using SSIS expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296769/how-to-convert-string-in-format-yyyymmdd-to-date-using-ssis-expression)

Comment: thank you, I'm new to SSIS this helped a million. Also here is link to best page to help with the conversion . thank you team x https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/09ef7f45-d31b-44a4-b58e-0053a276e369/ssis-type-cast-a-datetime-column?forum=sqlintegrationservices&prof=required

Answer (score 0):

try a script task

```
string fpath=""; //Set your filepath here

string fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fpath);

DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(fname.Substring(5, 2) + "/" + fname.Substring(7, 2) + "/" + fname.Substring(1, 4));
```