# How to convert Double-Precision Float [DT_R8] in to DateTime2 [DT_DBTIME2] in SSIS?

Tags: excel, ssis, type-conversion, data-conversion

How do I write an expression in SSIS for derived Column to convert my Column which is being identified as a Float [DT_R8] by the SSIS system in to a [DT_DBTIME2] format?

**Created Date_FLOAT**  20200621052345

**Created Date_DBTIME2**  2020-06-21 05:23:45

I have tried so many ways and nothing works...

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296769/how-to-convert-string-in-format-yyyymmdd-to-date-using-ssis-expression

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string in format yyyyMMdd to date using SSIS expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296769/how-to-convert-string-in-format-yyyymmdd-to-date-using-ssis-expression)